# Copy & rename element using XSL

Tags: xslt

I have an XML that goes like this:

```
<tu>
<prop type="x-idiom-source-ipath">DOMAIN/SUBDOMAIN/FILENAME</prop>
    <tuv xml:lang="IT-IT">
        <seg>Prova</seg>
    </tuv>
    <tuv xml:lang="EN-GB">
        <seg>Test</seg>
    </tuv>
</tu>
```

I'd like to copy the prop element twice and rename it:

```
<tu>
 <prop type="domain">DOMAIN/SUBDOMAIN/FILENAME</prop>
<prop type="subdomain">DOMAIN/SUBDOMAIN/FILENAME</prop>
<prop type="filename">DOMAIN/SUBDOMAIN/FILENAME</prop>
        <tuv xml:lang="IT-IT">
            <seg>Prova</seg>
        </tuv>
        <tuv xml:lang="EN-GB">
            <seg>Test</seg>
        </tuv>
    </tu>
```

How would I do that? I don't understand how to copy and duplicate the element, I'm not competent enough.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you could do simply:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="prop">
    <prop type="domain">
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </prop>
    <prop type="subdomain">
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </prop>
    <prop type="filename">
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </prop>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```